# MVC site that works locally not working after deployment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, odbc, sybase

I have an asp.net-mvc that that connects to a sybase IQ DB. It works locally but when I deploy it, I get an error saying:

**[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified]**

This webpage connect to a sybase DB using the:

```
ODBCConnection
```

class.  I don't see any other external dlls that seems to be references that weren't there before.

My connection string is (**NOTE**: i am replacing the actual info with []):

```
const string CONN_STRING = "DSN=SybaseDB;Eng=[DBNAME];Links=tcpip(Host=[server];Port=[MyPort]);UID=[username];PWD=[pwd];";
```

Can anyone give me any insight to what could be missing on the web server to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to [configure the ODBC driver](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc38421_1500/html/ntconfig/ntconfig64.htm) on the server.

Comment: but Darin, why didn't I need to do this on my local machine . . it seems like just having the connection string worked without configuring anything else

Comment: @ooo, look at the ODBC sources on your local machine to see if the DSN is present.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the DSN  ODBC connection on the remote server.

Comment: but i didn't need to do this locally ?? how is it working locally

Comment: @Darin - Apparently someone did.  At my organization there is actually code in the login script that creates ODBC connections.

Comment: @Darin - On another thought is the remote system 32bit or 64bit?